# How to match specific string and surrounding words in select statement with regex?

Tags: mysql, regex, select, mariadb

I want to select data from a field in a table that contains html formatted text, but only rows that contain a specific keyword.
Since the result would be bloated otherwise, I only want return the 2 previous and 3 next words around the keyword (and the keyword itself) I'm looking for.

I've tried to use the following regex

```
((?:[\w\"',.-]+\s*){0,2}[\"',.-]?keyword[\"',.-]?(?:\s*[\w\"',.-]+){0,3})
```

in a select like this

```
select id,title,REGEXP_SUBSTR(description,"((?:[\w\"',.-]+\s*){0,1}[\"',.-]?keyword[\"',.-]?(?:\s*[\w\"',.-]+){0,3})") from table;
```

But that seems only to return the keyword itself and not the surrounding words like it does here: https://regex101.com/r/xS5Gmz/1

How do I need to adapt the regex or select statement to achieve that?

I'm running MariDB 10.2.22.

Comment: Do you want to ignore the html tags?

Comment: Preferably yes. But it's ok if the result contains some html (like if the keyword is enclosed in e.g. <strong>).

Comment: `"((?:[\\w\"',.-]+\\s*)?[\"',.-]?keyword[\"',.-]?(?:\\s*[\\w\"',.-]+){0,3})"`